Strange Flickering Situation
Two parts to this whole situation...
Room A and Room B each have a light fixture. Room A has a single pole dimmer switch and Room B has a three way switch set up (one is a dimmer switch). When moving the dimmer through a certain range on the Room B lights, it causes Room A lights to flicker. I've changed out the dimmer switch in Room A and it didn't fix it. I presume these are on the same circuit. I cannot figure out what the problem is. I've also noticed now that Room A lights (LEDs) flicker when my new air conditioning heat pump is off. I see all sorts of people saying this happens when their system kicks on, but this is happening when the system is off.
Separately, but maybe somehow related, Room C (definitely different circuit) LED lights don't "flicker" but they seem to change brightness up and down on their own over 10-15 minutes here and there. I also haven't noticed this being related to the status of my AC.
I am stumped.
I also realized today that it's actually not just the AC...it's any high draw device when it's off. I shut my computer and some other equipment down just to test and the flickering became much worse again

Does "when it's off" mean, "when it turns off"? And are the high-draw devices on the same circuit? Finally, if you are in a North-America-style split-phase electricity supply location, test voltages at various outlets around the house, especially if you can be sure the outlets are on the two different legs of the split-phase supply: Flickering might also be a sign of a lost neutral, which can be seen when the voltages on the two legs see-saw around the nominal voltage, and the see-saw gets worse when high-current devices are used. Lost neutral is very dangerous.

Yes, so initially when I tested the "off" scenario I simply turned the temp up on my thermostat to make the heat pump and air handler shut off. Rapid flickering began. Today I decided to shut off other high load devices which do share the same circuit and same thing--rapid flickering. AC is on different circuit, of course...it's dedicated. The flickering seems to stop at full bright or full dim, and is less bad with these devices on. I am in the US. I'm a novice at this stuff so I'm not sure what different legs of the split phase supply means/is.

The change of brightness is usually a sign of voltage changes, which should not happen in most modern systems.  An old house might have a 60 amp service and with modern stuff it might be overloaded at times, a a modern 200 amp should not have that problem.  Your power company will come out to check a loose neutral for free

It's 200amp service.

A 200 amp service should have no flickering. As @crip659 says, call the power company and report a possible lost neutral. These are taken seriously, and they'll be able to tell you if it's their equipment (which they'll fix for free) or your equipment (which you'll have to pay to fix).

Yeah, I'd check for weird voltage behavior on both legs with various high-draw devices on and off

I had the utility company come out. They checked everything, ran the beast, etc. Nothing on their end.
